# Unable to access Open Office documents stored in windows paritition using ubuntu loaded from flash

Tags: windows, openoffice.org, copy, document

Windows doesn't boot, so I wanted to use ubuntu to copy my important files before formatting and reinstalling. the problem is that When copying folders somw files are left behind (the most important ones) and it says "Error splicing file: Input/output error" what does it mean? how can I access those files? I need help, thanks!

Comment: Sounds as if you have a corrupt hard drive. You may not be able to recover. Run diagnostic tools from windows (windows has better diagnostic tools for ntfs) and / or from linus run smartmontools - https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/monitor-harddisk-with-smartmon-on-ubuntu/ . In the future be sure to back up your data.